# How to get the current page URL in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I mean is how can I get the current relative URL, including the file name if there is one, i.e everything emphasized below:

```
http://hostname/app/app_dev.php/path/to/some/action?even=a%20query%20string
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried like

```
$request->getRequestUri();
```

but I'm getting the result like this

```
http://hostname/app/app_dev.php/admin/get
```

I want result like this

```
http://hostname/myproject_name/user/method/action
```

How to get in Symfony 3.4

Comment: You have three different URLs there, so I'm not sure what you want. All the info you need is in the Request object, take a look at the methods and documentation available for it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe following can help:

https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getUri

or

```
$request->attributes->get('_route')
```

Answer (score 2):

This represents the base URL of the current request prefixed by the path of the current request. Also it doesn't return URL's query string:

`$request->getSchemeAndHttpHost().$request->getPathInfo()`

For example for this real URL:

`http://127.0.0.1:8001/app_dev.php/homepage?page=3&size=20`

above snippet will return:

`http://127.0.0.1:8001/homepage`